# Expression type '(_, _.Stride) -> _' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, swift4

Help! I am encountering the error 'Expression type '(_, _.Stride) -> _' is ambiguous without more context'. Does anyone know why this is happening and a have solution to this? I am using Swift 4.
Code:

```
let offsetTime = 0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + offsetTime) { //Expression type '(_, _.Stride) -> _' is ambiguous without more context
    self.currentTaskForUser.text = "Starting\n" + note +  "in"
    self.timerDown(from: 3, to: 1)
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + offsetTime + 3) { //Expression type '(_, _.Stride) -> _' is ambiguous without more context
    self.currentTaskForUser.text = note
    let difficultyValue = Int(self.difficultyControl.titleForSegment(at: self.difficultyLevel.selectedSegmentIndex)!)!
    self.timerUp(from: 1, to: difficultyValue)
    self.offsetTime += 13
}
```

Comment: Try changing `let offsetTime = 0` to `let offsetTime = 0.0`.

Comment: @rmaddy Even that setting `offsetTime` to 0.0 will work somehow this expression still has readability ambiguous context. Maybe a more elegant solution will be this one: `let offsetTime : TimeInterval = 0`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression `.now()` returns the type `DispatchTime` which is a struct.

`let offsetTime = 0` initializes the variable as `Int`. The error is misleading, practically it's a type mismatch

---

Although the compiler can infer the type of an numeric literal

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
```

the most reliable way to add an `Int` literal or variable to a `DispatchTime` value is a `DispatchTimeInterval` case with associated value.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(offsetTime)
```

and

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(offsetTime) + .seconds(3))
```

There are four `DispatchTimeInterval` enumeration cases

- `.seconds(Int)`
- `.milliseconds(Int)`
- `.microseconds(Int)`
- `.nanoseconds(Int)`

Comment: The trick is if you want to do 0.5 seconds, just do 500 milliseconds